# Does using 'Ŝi' twice in a sentence 'always' mean they are different persons?

Tags: word-meaning

In this sentence,

> Ŝi dancas en sia ĉambro.

I know that a woman is dancing in her own room.

But if in this sentence,

> Ŝi dancas en ŝia ĉambro.

Does this 'necessarily' mean that one woman is dancing in 'another' woman's room?
Otherwise, can it be interpreted in both ways? (in her own room / another woman's room)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Ŝi dancas en ŝia ĉambro.
>
> Does this 'necessarily' mean that one woman is dancing in 'another' woman's room?

Yes, absolutely.  (But if you'll allow me to split hairs, the "ŝia" refers to a female, and not necessarily a fully-grown woman.  That is, the "ĉambro" could hypothetically refer to the subject's four-year-old daughter.)

> Otherwise, can it be interpreted in both ways?

No.  The words "lia", "ŝia", and "ilia" never refer back to the subject, hence the reason for the existence of the word "sia".  That is, the use of the word "sia(j)(n)" makes it clear that it's referring back to the subject.  So if "ŝia" is used, it necessarily refers to someone different than the subject.

(Note that this does not apply to the words "mia", "via", and "nia".  With those words, there is no confusion as to whose room we're talking about in the sentence "Mi dancas en mia ĉambro.")

---

There is one exception to what I stated above when I said that "lia/ŝia/ilia" never refers to the subject.  It has to do with the fact that "si" and "sia" can never be used in/as a subject.  So if you want to talk about someone and (for example) her brother, you would say:

- **Ŝi kaj ŝia frato promenis hieraŭ.**  (She and her brother went for a walk yesterday.)

You might be tempted to say "Ŝi kaj *sia* frato promenis hieraŭ" as the use of "sia" makes it clear that you're talking about the subject's brother.  However, this is wrong because "sia" is not supposed to be used as a subject, and that is why "ŝia" is used instead.

So that is the *only time* that "ŝia" can be interpreted both ways -- that is, as both her own brother and some other female's brother.

However, using "ŝi kaj ŝia frato" to refer to someone else's brother (and not the subject's brother) can be considered poor form, as it confuses who the "ŝi/she" words are referring to.  It would be just as confusing as this sentence in English:

- **She and her brother went for a walk.**

if you meant "she" and "her" to refer to different female persons.  If you really did intend for "she" and "her" to refer to different females, it's best just to specify who you mean instead of using "her/ŝia", in both English *and* Esperanto:

- **She and Maria's brother went for a walk.**
- **Ŝi kaj la frato de Maria promenis.**

Using two female pronouns ("she/ŝi" and "her/ŝia") so close together to refer to two different people is confusing in many languages -- and not just in English and Esperanto.

Comment: Well, that is not an exception, since *si* always referring to the subject implies that it cannot itself be part of a subject. A related topic is when to use *si* and *mem* together. Here I would like to refer to two blog posts by Thomas "Tomaso" Alexander: https://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/himself-mem-or-si/ and https://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/a-deeper-look-at-mem-and-si-esperanto-words-for-self-part-2/

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas:  You're correct in saying that it is not an exception if you mean regarding Esperanto rules.  But I wasn't talking about an exception to Esperanto rules -- I was talking about an "exception to what I stated above when I said that 'lia/ŝia/ilia' never refers to the subject."  (I had thought about mentioning that it wasn't a *real* exception regarding Esperanto rules, but I felt that that wouldn't have really contributed anything useful to the post.)

Comment: I wonder if the more advanced rules for 'si' are even usable/practical in casual speech. On the one hand you *have* to say «Ŝi kaj ŝia frato (...)» because both are part of the subject and you have to live with the ambiguity; on the other hand you *have* to say «Ŝi kun sia frato (...)» because the thing after *kun* technically is not part of the subject... I think most listeners would just rely on context whether the speaker gets it right or not (that doesn't mean that anything goes, there are many simpler sentences where *si* is easy to use and understand)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it necessarily means that she is dancing in the room of someone else. For the other meaning, you must use "sia".

Comment: A logician may frown upon this logic, but yes, **sia** and **ŝia** exclude eachother. **si** is overriding. The same for **de si**, **por si** and such.